# how to differentiate error returned while reading and for EOF in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, error-handling, ksh, file-processing

I have this task of uploading a delimited file and processing it. Once the processing is done, i either say its successful and if parsing fails, i need to throw the error. I'm reading this file line by line in child script and then processing it in main script (so i cant use ifs while read).

Im renaming to .done in case all lines are parsed. Now i would like to know when there is an error before EOF has reached so that i can rename it to .err. And what if i have a file without newline character at the end?

Structure is mostly as below:

```
Main script:
Calls parent script with filepath
gets the fileName and no of line in the files, calls the Child script with a nth line no in a loop until total no of lines are reached

Parent script:
#some validations to get the txt file from the list of files
... 
fileName=`ls -A1 *.txt`
...

Child script:
...
lineno=$1
fileName=$2
noOfLines=$3
line=`tail -$lineno $fileName | head -n1`

if [ $lineno -eq $noOfLines ] 
then
    noExt="${fileName%.*}"
    mv "$fileName" "$noExt.done" #success case
fi
```

Now i also need to rename the file to .err if its erroneous or parsing fails.
Pls let me know how do i catch the error.

Answer (score 1):

In shell, you read with `read`, not by iterating over the lines with `head` and `tail`. That being said, the POSIX standard states, in its description:

```
 EXIT STATUS

  The following exit values shall be returned:
 0
       Successful completion.
>0
       End-of-file was detected or an error occurred.
```

This means that you *cannot* distinguish between EOF and error on reading in shell.

As for the other subquestion, there are [good reasons why files *must* have a trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/2171120); I’ve seen sed(1) either not act on, or even strip, the last line if it did not have one, on some unixoid system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exit 1` or `exit 0` in your child script (use 0 for "no error"), and check the return value `$?` in the parent script. When you want to see the exit code of your tail command, this solution fails: `$?` will be the exitcode of the `head -n1`. In ksh you can't use the Bash solution ${PIPESTATUS}. The best way to handle this is replacing the tail..head construction by a single command (`sed ${lineno}'q;d' "${filename}"`).

Your example code is not complete, I do not see why you need to get one line for each call. For a large file this is quite some overhead. Please think it over!

Comment: `mksh` supports `${PIPESTATUS[*]}`.